# How to subtract one row from multiple rows by group, for data set with multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

I would like to learn how to subtract one row from multiple rows by group, and save the results as a data table/matrix in R. For example, take the following data frame:

`data.frame("patient" = c("a","a","a", "b","b","b","c","c","c"), "Time" = c(1,2,3), "Measure 1" = sample(1:100,size = 9,replace = TRUE), "Measure 2" = sample(1:100,size = 9,replace = TRUE),  "Measure 3" = sample(1:100,size = 9,replace = TRUE))`

```
       patient  Time  Measure.1  Measure.2  Measure.3
    1       a    1        19         5        75
    2       a    2        64        20        74
    3       a    3        40         4        78
    4       b    1        80        91        80
    5       b    2        48        31        73
    6       b    3        10         5         4
    7       c    1        30        67        55
    8       c    2        24        13        90
    9       c    3        45        31        88
```

For each patient, I would like to subtract the row where Time == 1 from all rows associated with that patient. The result would be:

```
       patient  Time  Measure.1  Measure.2  Measure.3
    1       a    1        0         0         0
    2       a    2        45        15       -1
    3       a    3        21       -1         3
    4       b    1        0         0         0
    5       b    2       -32       -60       -5
    6       b    3       -70       -86       -76
    7       c    1        0         0         0
    ....
```

I have tried the following code using the dplyr package, but to no avail:

```
raw_patient<- group_by(rawdata,patient, Time)  
baseline_patient <-mutate(raw_patient,cpls = raw_patient[,]- raw_patient["Time" == 0,])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there are multiple columns, we can use `mutate_at` by specifying the variables in `vars` and then subtract the elements from those elements in each column that corresponds to 'Time' 1 after grouping by 'patient'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(patient) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(matches("Measure")), funs(.- .[Time==1]))
# A tibble: 9 × 5
# Groups: patient [3]
#  patient  Time Measure.1 Measure.2 Measure.3
#    <chr> <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
#1       a     1         0         0         0
#2       a     2        45        15        -1
#3       a     3        21        -1         3
#4       b     1         0         0         0
#5       b     2       -32       -60        -7
#6       b     3       -70       -86       -76
#7       c     1         0         0         0
#8       c     2        -6       -54        35
#9       c     3        15       -36        33
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(patient = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c"), Time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Measure.1 = c(19L, 
64L, 40L, 80L, 48L, 10L, 30L, 24L, 45L), Measure.2 = c(5L, 20L, 
4L, 91L, 31L, 5L, 67L, 13L, 31L), Measure.3 = c(75L, 74L, 78L, 
80L, 73L, 4L, 55L, 90L, 88L)), .Names = c("patient", "Time", 
"Measure.1", "Measure.2", "Measure.3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I'm struggling to understand the documentation for dplyr- any suggestions for where to look? The vignette doesn't mention mutate_at or vars. The documentation in R is brief.