# How to subtract one row value from another and assign the value to a different row all in the same column, by group, for multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a strangely structured data frame with a grouping variable as a factor, followed by a character variable identifying expected vs. actual values for a series of ongoing days (where the actual values are recorded each day in a new column), as well as cumulatively, and I'm trying to calculate the difference between the expected and the actual values.

However, given the structure of the data, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this without getting into a whole mess of reshaping the data only to have to put it back together like this.

Is there a way I can calculate the differences, for each group, across all 'daily' columns, and then store the output in each 'original' column?

**Sample Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Variable = c("Day", "Actual.Cumulative", "Actual.Daily", "Expected.Cumulative", "Expected.Daily", "Diff.Daily", "Diff.Cumulative", "Day", "Actual.Cumulative", "Actual.Daily", "Expected.Cumulative", "Expected.Daily", "Diff.Daily", "Diff.Cumulative", "Day", "Actual.Cumulative", "Actual.Daily", "Expected.Cumulative", "Expected.Daily", "Diff.Daily", "Diff.Cumulative"), Day1 = c("Sunday", "1", "1", "3", "3", NA, NA, "Sunday", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, "Sunday", "8", "8", "5", "5", NA, NA), Day2 = c("Monday", "4", "3", "7", "4", NA, NA, "Monday", "2", "1", "3", "2", NA, NA, "Monday", "17", "9", "10", "5", NA, NA), Day3 = c("Tuesday", "6", "2", "10", "3", NA, NA, "Tuesday", "3", "1", "4", "1", NA, NA, "Tuesday", "29", "12", "14", "4", NA, NA), Day4 = c("Wednesday", "11", "5", "12", "2", NA, NA, "Wednesday", "4", "1", "5", "1", NA, NA, "Wednesday", "32", "3", "17", "3", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
df1
```

What I would like to do is fill  in the `Diff.Daily` cells in each "Day" column (i.e. `Day1`, `Day2`, etc.) by taking the difference between the `Actual.Daily` and `Expected.Daily` values for each `Group` (A, B, C), and then do similarly for `Diff.Cumulative` (i.e. `Actual.Cumulative - Expected.Cumulative`).

**Desired Output**

```
df2 <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Variable = c("Day", "Actual.Cumulative", "Actual.Daily", "Expected.Cumulative", "Expected.Daily", "Diff.Daily", "Diff.Cumulative", "Day", "Actual.Cumulative", "Actual.Daily", "Expected.Cumulative", "Expected.Daily", "Diff.Daily", "Diff.Cumulative", "Day", "Actual.Cumulative", "Actual.Daily", "Expected.Cumulative", "Expected.Daily", "Diff.Daily", "Diff.Cumulative"), Day1 = c("Sunday", "1", "1", "3", "3", "-2", "-2", "Sunday", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "Sunday", "8", "8", "5", "5", "3", "3"), Day2 = c("Monday", "4", "3", "7", "4", "-1", "-3", "Monday", "2", "1", "3", "2", "-1", "-1", "Monday", "17", "9", "10", "5", "4", "7"), Day3 = c("Tuesday", "6", "2", "10", "3", "-1", "-4", "Tuesday", "3", "1", "4", "1", "0", "-1", "Tuesday", "29", "12", "14", "4", "8", "15"), Day4 = c("Wednesday", "11", "5", "12", "2", "3", "-1", "Wednesday", "4", "1", "5", "1", "0", "-1", "Wednesday", "32", "3", "17", "3", "0", "15")), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
df2
```

Here you can see for Group A on Day 1, `Diff.Daily` = -2 as expected from `Actual.Daily` of 1 minus an `Expected.Daily` of 3.

**My Attempts**

As the "Day" columns are of character class because of their mixed nature, I know I need to wrap the calculations with `as.numeric()`, and I can calculate the values individually for each column:

```
Diff.Cumulative <- as.numeric(df1[df1$Variable == "Actual.Cumulative", "Day1"]) - as.numeric(df1[df1$Variable == "Expected.Cumulative", "Day1"])
```

But I'm struggling with how to expand this to all "Day" columns and to fit it into the current data frame structure. I came across a [similar but ultimately different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899377/how-to-subtract-one-row-from-multiple-rows-by-group-for-data-set-with-multiple) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with the help of a helper function.

```
library(dplyr)

change_values <- function(sub1, sub2, to, var, value) {
  x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(value))
  x[match(to, var)] <- x[match(sub1, var)] - x[match(sub2, var)]
  x[1] <- value[1]
  x
}


df1 %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Day'), ~change_values('Actual.Daily', 
        'Expected.Daily', 'Diff.Daily', Variable, .)), 
         across(starts_with('Day'), ~change_values('Actual.Cumulative', 
        'Expected.Cumulative', 'Diff.Cumulative', Variable, .))) %>%
  ungroup
```

This returns -

```
#   Group            Variable   Day1   Day2    Day3      Day4
#1      A                 Day Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#2      A   Actual.Cumulative      1      4       6        11
#3      A        Actual.Daily      1      3       2         5
#4      A Expected.Cumulative      3      7      10        12
#5      A      Expected.Daily      3      4       3         2
#6      A          Diff.Daily     -2     -1      -1         3
#7      A     Diff.Cumulative     -2     -3      -4        -1
#8      B                 Day Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#9      B   Actual.Cumulative      1      2       3         4
#10     B        Actual.Daily      1      1       1         1
#11     B Expected.Cumulative      1      3       4         5
#12     B      Expected.Daily      1      2       1         1
#13     B          Diff.Daily      0     -1       0         0
#14     B     Diff.Cumulative      0     -1      -1        -1
#15     C                 Day Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#16     C   Actual.Cumulative      8     17      29        32
#17     C        Actual.Daily      8      9      12         3
#18     C Expected.Cumulative      5     10      14        17
#19     C      Expected.Daily      5      5       4         3
#20     C          Diff.Daily      3      4       8         0
#21     C     Diff.Cumulative      3      7      15        15
```